# Query Data from www or nowww?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects

I'm currently looking at a Google Webmaster Tools Account that has been set up by the client using both www and nowww. Traffic is being redirected to the www version.

In order to analyze Search Queries correctly, which of the two Accounts should I use? I would go for the www account, since it is where traffic is flowing to and where numbers are slight higher.

Still wanted to check though.

Comment: Yep, go where the users are.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll stick with the www version. However, I do see the same values on both installations. Top pages are www on both. Is it possible to tell why that is while only having restricted access? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget to approve an answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If traffic is redirected to `www`, then you should not see `non-www` query data anymore after some time. Else, it means there is an issue with the redirection.

Focus on `www` query data only for your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Google's webmaster tools search queries will always return what's in the search results, because you are using non-www to www you should have no non-www urls therefore no results will be returned. In short you should only look at which one is being used i.e the one that is visitable without a redirect. In your case you should be looking at the same account of which your visitors visit without no redirections.